# How to get the JSON code of a web page

Tags: java, json

Am working on J2ee web application and am trying to get the code JSON of a web page via it's url in purpose to parse it later. I've already tried the code below:

```
          package so4308554;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;``
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JsonReader {

  private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
      sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
      String jsonText = readAll(rd);
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
      return json;
    } finally {
      is.close();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
    JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552");
    System.out.println(json.toString());
    System.out.println(json.get("id"));
  }
}
```

But it works only with the given url if i put another one i get this exception:
"A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1"
 I think i can't get the Json content of web page if it is coded by html... any idea of what could be the causes??????? And how can i resolve my problem???

Comment: error says everything... JSON is not formed properly.. Give URL thats not working

Comment: It does not make sense. Trying to parse HTML as JSON is the same thing as trying to compile a Java program with a C compiler. If you want to parse some JSON, you should target an URL which returns JSON, not HTML.

Comment: Perhaps he wants the java program to connect to a website backend or API and speak http, as if it were a browser,  thereby receiving some JSON from the backend.

Comment: print the output and check whether it starts with something else

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you trying to get json out of an html web page?
2. If the answer to the previous question is "No", validate the json you're trying to parse with something like this: http://jsonlint.com/, and check out the results.

Comment: My answer is yes. I am not trying to validate the json, what am wondering is how to get the json code from a web page via it's url.

Comment: Well... Usually you get HTML from web pages, not JSON! If you want to parse HTML you need a HTML parser, not a JSON parser.

Comment: Look my problem is when i parse a html it tooks so much time especially am parsing a list of Html pages. To optimize my programm i thought of parsing the JSON code instead of HTML. 
If you have better solution, i will be very thankfull :)

Comment: ok, but from what service (you get JSON from a web service, not from a web page) do you wish to get JSON? Facebook? If it's Facebook I recommend you this api: http://restfb.com/. It does already a lot of parsing work for you.

Comment: thanks for your answer but NO: not facebook i wanna parse general web pages

Comment: Look, you just can't pick a random web page written in HTML and parse it like it was JSON. If the resources you want are not available in JSON by the provider you're accessing, there's nothing you can do about it.