# Retrieve Json Data within Java

Tags: java, json, gson, here-api

i would like to ask for your help in this matter. 
I have never worked with Json / Gson before, here is what i want to do.

1. For a studyproject we want to use the HERE API that provides a String that contains the time of a route between two adresses. Generating the URL that contains the two adresses latitude and longitude works pretty good already. If i click on the link its opening this page:

JSON VIEW:

[image: 1]

RAW String:

```
{
  "response": {
    "metaInfo": {
      "timestamp": "2020-06-09T06:25:38Z",
      "mapVersion": "8.30.109.150",
      "moduleVersion": "7.2.202021-7166",
      "interfaceVersion": "2.6.76",
      "availableMapVersion": [
        "8.30.109.150"
      ]
    },
    "route": [
      {
        "waypoint": [
          {
            "linkId": "+1131186975",
            "mappedPosition": {
              "latitude": 51.3547214,
              "longitude": 6.1533969
            },
            "originalPosition": {
              "latitude": 51.3547199,
              "longitude": 6.1534
            },
            "type": "stopOver",
            "spot": 0.1907895,
            "sideOfStreet": "neither",
            "mappedRoadName": "Tegelseweg",
            "label": "Tegelseweg - N271",
            "shapeIndex": 0,
            "source": "user"
          },
          {
            "linkId": "+1151950438",
            "mappedPosition": {
              "latitude": 52.3654734,
              "longitude": 4.8532104
            },
            "originalPosition": {
              "latitude": 52.3654734,
              "longitude": 4.8532099
            },
            "type": "stopOver",
            "spot": 0.3333333,
            "sideOfStreet": "neither",
            "mappedRoadName": "Hoofdweg",
            "label": "Hoofdweg",
            "shapeIndex": 1367,
            "source": "user"
          }
        ],
        "mode": {
          "type": "fastest",
          "transportModes": [
            "truck"
          ],
          "trafficMode": "disabled",
          "feature": []
        },
        "leg": [
          {
            "start": {
              "linkId": "+1131186975",
              "mappedPosition": {
                "latitude": 51.3547214,
                "longitude": 6.1533969
              },
              "originalPosition": {
                "latitude": 51.3547199,
                "longitude": 6.1534
              },
              "type": "stopOver",
              "spot": 0.1907895,
              "sideOfStreet": "neither",
              "mappedRoadName": "Tegelseweg",
              "label": "Tegelseweg - N271",
              "shapeIndex": 0,
              "source": "user"
            },
            "end": {
              "linkId": "+1151950438",
              "mappedPosition": {
                "latitude": 52.3654734,
                "longitude": 4.8532104
              },
              "originalPosition": {
                "latitude": 52.3654734,
                "longitude": 4.8532099
              },
              "type": "stopOver",
              "spot": 0.3333333,
              "sideOfStreet": "neither",
              "mappedRoadName": "Hoofdweg",
              "label": "Hoofdweg",
              "shapeIndex": 1367,
              "source": "user"
            },
            "length": 183631,
            "travelTime": 8364,
            "maneuver": [
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 51.3547214,
                  "longitude": 6.1533969
                },
                "instruction": "Head toward <span class=\"toward_street\">Hulsterweg</span> on <span class=\"street\">Tegelseweg</span> <span class=\"number\">(N271)</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">123 m</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 16,
                "length": 123,
                "id": "M1",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 51.3555801,
                  "longitude": 6.154511
                },
                "instruction": "Make a U-Turn onto <span class=\"next-street\">Tegelseweg</span> <span class=\"number\">(N271)</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">274 m</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 126,
                "length": 274,
                "id": "M2",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 51.3541317,
                  "longitude": 6.1523652
                },
                "instruction": "Turn <span class=\"direction\">right</span> and take ramp onto <span class=\"number\">A73</span> toward <span class=\"sign\"><span lang=\"nl\">Eindhoven</span>/<span lang=\"nl\">Nijmegen</span></span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">64.3 km</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 2746,
                "length": 64315,
                "id": "M3",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 51.8447292,
                  "longitude": 5.7708693
                },
                "instruction": "Keep <span class=\"direction\">right</span> onto <span class=\"number\">A73</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">3.8 km</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 166,
                "length": 3793,
                "id": "M4",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 51.856252,
                  "longitude": 5.7191348
                },
                "instruction": "Take the exit toward <span class=\"sign\"><span lang=\"nl\">Rotterdam</span>/<span lang=\"nl\">Arnhem</span></span> onto <span class=\"number\">A50</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">2.3 km</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 102,
                "length": 2338,
                "id": "M5",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 51.8729675,
                  "longitude": 5.7295954
                },
                "instruction": "Keep <span class=\"direction\">left</span> onto <span class=\"number\">A50</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">2.5 km</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 103,
                "length": 2471,
                "id": "M6",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 51.893481,
                  "longitude": 5.7424915
                },
                "instruction": "Keep <span class=\"direction\">left</span> onto <span class=\"number\">A50</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">1.4 km</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 61,
                "length": 1440,
                "id": "M7",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 51.9014311,
                  "longitude": 5.7587779
                },
                "instruction": "Take the exit toward <span class=\"sign\"><span lang=\"nl\">Rotterdam</span>/<span lang=\"nl\">Tiel</span></span> onto <span class=\"number\">A15</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">39.8 km</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 1735,
                "length": 39789,
                "id": "M8",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 51.8583441,
                  "longitude": 5.2429676
                },
                "instruction": "Take the exit toward <span class=\"sign\"><span lang=\"nl\">Utrecht</span></span> onto <span class=\"number\">A2</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">59.0 km</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 2555,
                "length": 58990,
                "id": "M9",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 52.3197055,
                  "longitude": 4.9161673
                },
                "instruction": "Keep <span class=\"direction\">right</span> onto <span class=\"number\">E35</span> <span class=\"next-street\">(Knooppunt Amstel)</span> toward <span class=\"sign\"><span lang=\"nl\">E19</span>/<span lang=\"nl\">RING</span>/<span lang=\"nl\">Luchthaven Schiphol</span>/<span lang=\"nl\">Zaanstad</span>/<span lang=\"nl\">A10</span></span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">714 m</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 32,
                "length": 714,
                "id": "M10",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 52.3259926,
                  "longitude": 4.9142146
                },
                "instruction": "Keep <span class=\"direction\">left</span> onto <span class=\"next-street\">Knooppunt Amstel</span> toward <span class=\"sign\"><span lang=\"nl\">Luchthaven Schiphol</span>/<span lang=\"nl\">A10</span>/<span lang=\"nl\">E19</span></span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">1.1 km</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 70,
                "length": 1140,
                "id": "M11",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 52.3305416,
                  "longitude": 4.9042583
                },
                "instruction": "Keep <span class=\"direction\">right</span> onto <span class=\"number\">A10</span> <span class=\"next-street\">(Ring Amsterdam)</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">6.3 km</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 321,
                "length": 6343,
                "id": "M12",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 52.3544562,
                  "longitude": 4.8427069
                },
                "instruction": "Take exit <span class=\"exit\">6</span> toward <span class=\"sign\"><span lang=\"nl\">Osdorp</span>/<span lang=\"nl\">Overtoomse Veld</span>/<span lang=\"nl\">Oud-West</span></span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">367 m</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 63,
                "length": 367,
                "id": "M13",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 52.3577499,
                  "longitude": 4.8430288
                },
                "instruction": "Turn <span class=\"direction\">right</span> onto <span class=\"next-street\">Cornelis Lelylaan</span> <span class=\"number\">(s106)</span> toward <span class=\"sign\"><span lang=\"nl\">Oud-West</span>/<span lang=\"nl\">Centrum</span></span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">555 m</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 77,
                "length": 555,
                "id": "M14",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 52.3579645,
                  "longitude": 4.8511183
                },
                "instruction": "Keep <span class=\"direction\">left</span> toward <span class=\"sign\"><span lang=\"nl\">De Baarsjes</span></span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">126 m</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 31,
                "length": 126,
                "id": "M15",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 52.358104,
                  "longitude": 4.8529422
                },
                "instruction": "Take the <span class=\"exit\">2nd exit</span> from Surinameplein roundabout onto <span class=\"next-street\">Surinameplein</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">134 m</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 39,
                "length": 134,
                "id": "M16",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 52.3590052,
                  "longitude": 4.8534894
                },
                "instruction": "Continue on <span class=\"next-street\">Hoofdweg</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">719 m</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 121,
                "length": 719,
                "id": "M17",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 52.3654734,
                  "longitude": 4.8532104
                },
                "instruction": "Arrive at <span class=\"street\">Hoofdweg</span>.",
                "travelTime": 0,
                "length": 0,
                "id": "M18",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "summary": {
          "distance": 183631,
          "trafficTime": 8427,
          "baseTime": 8364,
          "flags": [
            "tollroad",
            "tunnel",
            "motorway",
            "builtUpArea"
          ],
          "text": "The trip takes <span class=\"length\">184 km</span> and <span class=\"time\">2:19 h</span>.",
          "travelTime": 8364,
          "_type": "RouteSummaryType"
        }
      }
    ],
    "language": "en-us"
  }
}
```

I only need to have the yellow marked part of the whole Json String (traffic time: 8364). 
What is the easiest way to get this? 
My current code looks like this, it returns null:

```
 URL host = new URL(uri);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) host.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");


    System.out.println(
        "Response code - message: " + con.getResponseCode() + " - " + con.getResponseMessage());

    if (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
```

The con.getResponseMessage prints Connection okay, so the link works.

2. I googled several solutions but i cannot import the necessary libraries, IntelliJ displays an error if i try to import them for applying this solution i found on stackoverflow: 
   [How to get the JSON code of a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507933/how-to-get-the-json-code-of-a-web-page)

Import of Json Library:

[image]

Im new to import external libraries thats why i dont know how to handle this

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Please [edit] and update the question with json as text instead of image.

Comment: Checkout `Rest-Assured`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create model classes and use `GSON` to parse them. This will make it easy for you to access any field from json response.

1. Model classes

```java
class ResponseData {
    private Response response;
    // getters and setters
}

class Response {
    private List<Route> route;
    // getters and setters
}

class Route {
    private Summary summary;
    // getters and setters
}

class Summary {
    private Long trafficTime;
    // getters and setters
}
```

2. Parse json response to models

```java
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Gson gson = new Gson();
ResponseData responseData = gson.fromJson(reader, ResponseData.class);
responseData.getResponse().getRoute().forEach(route -> System.out.println(route.getSummary().getTrafficTime()));
```

**Output:**

> 8427

Comment: you made my day. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Gson probaly, keep going this way and don't need to import any Json lib.

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement json = parser.parse(your_json_string);
JsonArray route = json.getAsJsonObject().get("response").getAsJsonObject().get("route")getAsJsonArray();
int yourTrafficTime = route.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("summary").getAsJsonObject().get("trafficTime").getAsInt();
```